# Inserción a tabla multitudes usuarios, determinando el ultimo id auto incrementable que ingreso cada usuario

Tags: mysql, sql

Buen día primero contextualizo:
Tengo múltiples usuario que siguen el siguiente flujo: Insert --> Select
Ver codígo: http://rextester.com/LAAY39587

```
drop table if exists tbl;

create table tbl (
   id int primary key AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  valor int not null,
  texto varchar(50) not null
);

insert into tbl (valor, texto) values (1, 'aaa');
insert into tbl (valor, texto) values (5, 'eee');
insert into tbl (valor, texto) values (2, 'bbb');
insert into tbl (valor, texto) values (4, 'ddd');
insert into tbl (valor, texto) values (3, 'ccc');

select *
 from tbl
 order by id desc
 limit 1;

drop table tbl;
```

Este código lo que hace en ultimas es sacar el ultimo registro ingresado, mi pregunta es:

¿Será que si tengo múltiples usuarios ingresando un registro a la misma tabla  al mismo tiempo, pasaría el Primer caso que sería: me regresará el ultimo registro que ingresó X usuario O pasaría el Segundo caso: me regresará el registro del ultimo dato que asimilo el motor de BD?

En caso de ser el segundo caso. ¿Como hago para determinar el ultimo registro que ingreso cada usuario?

NOTA: No se puede almacenar el id del usuario, no se pueden tener más columnas de las que tiene la tabla.

GRACIAS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estamos hablando del motor INNODB, por defecto las transacciones ocurren en el modo [READ COMMITED](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html#isolevel_read-committed).

Esto implica que un INSERT adquirirá un bloqueo sobre la fila que está insertando. Un SELECT simultáneo esperará a que el insert haya liberado el lock antes de entregar un resultado. Esto aplica si muchos usuarios están insertando y tú ejecutas el select para saber el último ID.

Ahora bien, si tú quieres devolverle a cada usuario el ID del registro que él acaba de insertar, y considerando que el ID es autoincremental y por tanto no debiera especificarse en la query de inserción, cada usuario podría hacer:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (texto) values ('eee');
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Y obtendría el ID de su última inserción independientemente de lo que otro usuario esté insertando en el mismo momento, debido a que `LAST_INSERT_ID` es consistente para cada conexión:

> The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a
>   **per-connection basis**. This means that the value returned by the
>   function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated
>   for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column by **that**
>   **client**. This value cannot be affected by other clients, even if they
>   generate AUTO_INCREMENT values of their own. This behavior ensures
>   that **each client can retrieve its own ID without concern for the**
>   **activity of other clients**, and without the need for locks or
>   transactions.

Ref: [MySQL LAST_INSERT_ID](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Finalmente, si intentas insertar un ID arbitrario en un campo que es la llave primaria y autoincremental, la inserción puede fallar (si el ID ya existe) o puede hacer inconsistente el autoincremento.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!, aprendí algo nuevo.